# sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7 fails to verify PKCS#7 signature of type RSASSA-PSS

Tags: java, rsa, verify, pkcs#7

I am trying to create a PKCS#7 signature file from a raw signature of type RSASSA-PSS. The verification of the raw signature is successful but the verification of the PKCS#7 object fails with `NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA256withRSASSA-PSS Signature not available`.

The code is below. Calling `verifyRawSignature` returns true but calling `verifyPkcs7Signature` fails with the stacktrace in the javadoc. There is probably an error in `createPkcs7` but where is it?

```
package dev.example;

import sun.security.pkcs.ContentInfo;
import sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7;
import sun.security.pkcs.SignerInfo;
import sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId;
import sun.security.x509.X500Name;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidParameterSpecException;
import java.security.spec.MGF1ParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.PSSParameterSpec;

public class Pkcs7Tool {

    /**
     * The data to verify.
     */
    private final byte[] data;

    /**
     * The raw 256 signature bytes as returned from the remote signing service.
     */
    private final byte[] rawSignature;

    /**
     * The signing certificate;
     */
    private final X509Certificate certificate;

    public Pkcs7Tool(byte[] data, byte[] rawSignature, X509Certificate certificate) {
        this.data = data;
        this.rawSignature = rawSignature;
        this.certificate = certificate;
    }

    /**
     * Verifies the raw signature.
     */
    public boolean verifyRawSignature() {
        try {
            final Signature signatureVerifier = Signature.getInstance( "RSASSA-PSS" );
            signatureVerifier.setParameter( new PSSParameterSpec( "SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, 32, 1 ) );
            signatureVerifier.initVerify(certificate);
            signatureVerifier.update(data);
            return signatureVerifier.verify(rawSignature);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | InvalidKeyException | SignatureException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed to verify raw signature", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verifies the signature packaged into a pkcs7 file.
     * Fails with
     * <pre>
     * java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA256withRSASSA-PSS Signature not available
     *  at java.base/java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:267)
     *  at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.SignerInfo.verify(SignerInfo.java:431)
     *  at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:578)
     *  at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:595)
     *  at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:617)
     *  at dev.example.Pkcs7Tool.verifyPkcs7Signature(Pkcs7Tool.java:60)
     * </pre>
     */
    public SignerInfo[] verifyPkcs7Signature() {
        try {
            return createPkcs7().verify();
        } catch (SignatureException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed to verify pkcs7 signature", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a DER encoded PKCS7 file from a raw signature.
     * Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/56015231/1581276
     */
    public PKCS7 createPkcs7() {
        final X500Name xName = X500Name.asX500Name(certificate.getIssuerX500Principal());
        final BigInteger serial = certificate.getSerialNumber();
        final AlgorithmId digestAlgorithmId = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.SHA256_oid);
        final AlgorithmParameters algorithmParameters;
        try {
            algorithmParameters = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("RSASSA-PSS");
            final AlgorithmParameterSpec algorithmParameterSpec = new PSSParameterSpec( "SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, 32, 1 );
            algorithmParameters.init(algorithmParameterSpec);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidParameterSpecException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to initialize signature algorithm parameters", e);
        }
        final AlgorithmId signAlgorithmId = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.RSASSA_PSS_oid, algorithmParameters);
        final SignerInfo signerInfo = new SignerInfo(xName, serial, digestAlgorithmId, signAlgorithmId, rawSignature);
        final ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(ContentInfo.DATA_OID, null);
        return new PKCS7(new AlgorithmId[]{digestAlgorithmId}, contentInfo,
                new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{certificate},
                new SignerInfo[]{signerInfo});
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `sun.*` packages is not recommened.

Comment: [Fixed in 16](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8242068) although to verify a PKCS7 _detached_ signature you need to pass the data (and you have to force opens for the 'internal' classes, as the President notes)

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085! Switching to Java 17 and adding `data` to the call of `verify` helped indeed.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk but what do you recommend? My input is the data, the certificate, and the raw signature that is created by a non JCA system which keeps the private key hidden. How do I create a PKCS#7 file from these 3 inputs without using `sun.*` packages?